# How safe is a link with MD5 hash

Tags: php, https

For my webpage I use a (HTTPS) link instead of a password to change the page. In the link I use 2 MD5 hashes behind each other, the base of the MD5 is random (ID of the advertisement and some other not to guess information).
Of course I don’t want that other people than the one who has the email with the link, change the page. How safe is this solution actually?  What other options are there, I don’t want to use a password ….

Example link:

https://www.huurhulp.nl/wijzigen/wijzigen.php?wijzigen_adv=14&code=523a98367bfb05765fb86a2535966aad

Is it possible that the link get's in hands of somebody else if the email with the link is not send forward? Is eavesdropping possible?

Comment: I didn't understand a thing. You should know that is enough 1 `MD5` hash

Comment: That is bearer token based authentication. Nothing wrong with that, if you can control that those links don't leak. Consider expiration date, manual expiration, links that only work once and random numbers instead of hashes.

Comment: We can not tell you how secure that is unless we know which kind of security you are asking about. But even if you would tell us, we would probably need to close the question then as too localized, because we would like to see general problems questioned here, not those questions that turn out of an itch you have to scratch right now for whatever reason of time and which might not play any role ten days later. So what do you want to learn about in specific?

Comment: It is safer if you combine this all with the users ip address ;)

Comment: @Bondye: Unless that shared secret changes.

Comment: Can you show us what an example link looks like?

Comment: @davisschwartz https://www.huurhulp.nl/wijzigen/wijzigen.php?wijzigen_adv=14&code=523a98367bfb05765fb86a2535966aad

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe there is no way for you to revoke one of those links (which are in effect bearer tokens).

This could be a problem, if you know that one of them has leaked, and you need to block access through that link (and issue a new one).

Ideally, you'd use completely random tokens for every page, that you store in a database.

Other options to increase security are expiration after a time and expiration after use (if your flow is email-based, you can send out the new token when that happens).

I think a good example would be how Flickr implements Guest Passes: you can create any number of them, and you can individually revoke them.

Comment: I now use a random Hash (because of the not to guess data in the hash) and i store this hash in the database. The user uses this link multiple times to edit his advertisement, het could even bookmark this link. I use HTTPS so i think the link could not be available for hackers or other not nice persons, but don't know it for sure....